# Problem in displaying scrollbar with Dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, menu

I am trying to make a menu with many items, sub items. I want to display scroll bar along with the items if they are increased. I want to do same with sub menus and so on.

Here is the [example](http://article-stack.com/examples/menu2.html) about what i am doing.

The problem is, It is displaying horizontal scroll bar, if sub menu again have some items as child. I want to show only vertical scroll bar. and want to pop out sub menues.

Link of [css](http://article-stack.com/examples/superfish.css) i am using.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this kind of behavior is outside the scope of CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify separate horizontal and vertical overflow behaviors:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Your CSS reference material should have told you that. This will of course make a complete mess of any submenus that try to pop out along the x-axis.

Scrollbars in a menu will also make your users hate you and possibly win you a place in the User Interface Hall of Shame or a post on http://thedailywtf.com/. If you're thinking about doing something like this in the real world, don't do it. Think of a less irritating way to organize your navigation.

Comment: +vote for your suggestion about not to display scroll bar. But hiding overflow for a particular direction can hide the scrollbar. But it can not pop out the submenu. :(

Comment: And that should be a hint that you're doing things you shouldn't. If you want to mix menus and scrollbars like that you're going to end up having to position everything by hand with `position:absolute`.